# Multiple ASIDownloadCaches

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

I am just reading through the how to use part of the [How to use ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) notes and would like more clarification on setting up multiple caches.

In the notes for the downloadcache it says

> You aren’t restricted to a single cache - you can create as many
>   caches as you like. When you create a cache yourself, you must set the
>   storage path for the cache - this should be a folder you have write
>   access to:

Then shows this peice of code.

```
ASIDownloadCache *cache = [[[ASIDownloadCache alloc] init] autorelease];
[cache setStoragePath:@"/Users/ben/Documents/Cached-Downloads"];

// Don't forget - you are responsible for retaining your cache!
[self setMyCache:cache];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadCache:[self myCache]];
```

I would like to know where this file is? on the device I suppose? but also how do I make the file and how do I give it write access etc?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `setStoragePath` is just a directory. The example you give is a Mac OS path, you'd need to pick an appropriate location on iOS; the Q&As from Apple should guide you as to appropriate places to use:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1699/_index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

You just need to create the directory you want to use; there's no need to give it any special permissions.

For any given URL stored in the cache, you can find it's location using `ASIDownloadCache`'s `pathToCachedResponseDataForURL` method.

Answer (score 0):

I read the ASIHTTPDownloadCache.h file I have in my project not sure what I would find however I think I did find my answer in it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ASICacheDelegate.h"

@interface ASIDownloadCache : NSObject <ASICacheDelegate> {

    // The default cache policy for this cache
    // Requests that store data in the cache will use this cache policy if their cache policy is set to ASIUseDefaultCachePolicy
    // Defaults to ASIAskServerIfModifiedWhenStaleCachePolicy
    ASICachePolicy defaultCachePolicy;

    // The directory in which cached data will be stored
    // Defaults to a directory called 'ASIHTTPRequestCache' in the temporary directory
    NSString *storagePath;

    // Mediates access to the cache
    NSRecursiveLock *accessLock;

    // When YES, the cache will look for cache-control / pragma: no-cache headers, and won't reuse store responses if it finds them
    BOOL shouldRespectCacheControlHeaders;
}

// Returns a static instance of an ASIDownloadCache
// In most circumstances, it will make sense to use this as a global cache, rather than creating your own cache
// To make ASIHTTPRequests use it automatically, use [ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
+ (id)sharedCache;

// A helper function that determines if the server has requested data should not be cached by looking at the request's response headers
+ (BOOL)serverAllowsResponseCachingForRequest:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;

@property (assign, nonatomic) ASICachePolicy defaultCachePolicy;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *storagePath;
@property (retain) NSRecursiveLock *accessLock;
@property (assign) BOOL shouldRespectCacheControlHeaders;
@end
```

The main point being.

storage path -

```
// The directory in which cached data will be stored
        // Defaults to a directory called 'ASIHTTPRequestCache' in the temporary directory
```

The only thing Im not sure of is what name it uses to store the cache.. I think its probably the URL but cannot say with any certainty because I have not tested it.